# Mounting mailbox parallel to column

Tags: mailbox

I would like to mount a mailbox on the side of a column at my entryway. Every mount I have seen points the mailbox opening straight outward, away from the column center. However I would like my mailbox to be parallel to the column center.

Here is some ascii art to illustrate.

- Symbol for the column: `[]`
- Symbol for the mailbox, with front/back at the ends: `|`

Standard mount, looking down from the top:

```
[]
|
```

What I’m looking for, also looking down from the top:

```
[]|
```

Has anyone tried this before? Is there a set of hardware I can buy to achieve this?

**EDIT**

The column is plywood, with a slight taper reducing the width from ground toward ceiling.

The mailbox is a standard aluminum rounded-top mailbox.

**EDIT 2**

Pictures:

[image: Current mailbox next to post]
[image: New location to move mailbox]
[image: Mailbox mounting details]

Comment: Will depend on the mailbox and column.  I have a plain steel box mounted on top of a wood post.  It would not be that hard to drill a few holes in the side and mount the way you want.

Comment: Some photos of your mailbox and your column would sure help your cause.

Comment: @Huesmann thanks for suggestion; added pictures above

Comment: Why not just screw it through the side, directly to the plywood side of the column?  You'll need a stubby screwdriver, but easily doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of L brackets screwed to the plywood column and to a bit of wood fitted to the bottom of the mailbox will do this easily and without compromising the weather-tightness of the box.

Most "standard" round-top mailboxes have a recess on the bottom to take a mounting board, and holes to fasten into the mounting board. So you just mount the mounting board as a shelf, spaced far enough off the face of the column to permit the mailbox to fit, and any rain that gets between them to drain freely.

Comment: Seems like the L bracket is pretty close. I could only find 90-degree brackets. Are there other types of brackets for other angles? I'm guessing my angle is 85 or 80 degrees - see picture above. Maybe I could just bend one to the angle I want.

Comment: I ended up moving the whole mailbox, to the right side, and leaving it mounted on the existing posts. Had I gone with the side mounting, I would have used this approach, so I will mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Drill 2 holes in the side of the mailbox slightly slanted ( / ).

Screw through the inside of the mailbox into the column.

Use [Fender washers](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-1-1-4-in-Zinc-Plated-Fender-Washer-100-Piece-per-Box-804790/204276327?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK-71700000109986253-58700008375337160-92700076237673158&gclid=Cj0KCQjwx5qoBhDyARIsAPbMagCd7y_iAUxGSw8s0uhDN9o2Na4IHATStQ-ra7fLAv1v3U4Xf8grD7oaAvwKEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and wood screws.  I like [Teks screws](https://www.zoro.com/teks-sheet-metal-screw-8-x-34-in-zinc-plated-steel-truss-head-600-pk-21506/i/G105673533/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping%20feed&utm_content=free%20google%20shopping%20clicks&campaignid=19979164537&productid=G105673533&v=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwx5qoBhDyARIsAPbMagBmtn7LR2n4IKFXA8HZqdVzVT-pFAt7Z_OTVsMj5rKH01LIPdQXZ8UaAjFnEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) (Even though they are rated as metal screws.) I find they are great for this type of application and very easy to screw.

If needed use a fender washer or 2 between the mailbox and column on the upper screw, to adjust for the taper.

Comment: Thanks, I added details to post.